# Why can't I change element in reversed list?

Tags: python, list, reverse

This is my code. I want to change "7" to "999" and print (1,2,3,4,5,6,999) with this method but it prints list1 unchanged (1,2,3,4,5,6,7). I don't understand why it doesn't change.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

list1[::-1][0] = 999
print (list1)
```

Comment: Try : `list1[-1] = 999`

Comment: You're not modifying `list1`, you're modifying a copy of it.

Comment: You changed an element in the reversed list just fine. You never told Python to do anything to the original list, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list1[::-1]
```

This returns a new list. Modifying it doesn't affect the original list. If all you want to do is change the last element you can do it directly with a negative index.

```
list1[-1] = 999
```